# How to simulate a property of a symmetric NAT?

Tags: iptables, nat, udp

For the testing of the STUN/TURN configuration I'd like to block all incoming UDP traffic except for the ports on which I've sent something to the remote server recently.

Ports are not known in advance.

I don't need the internal/external IPs aspect of NAT. There are just two machines on the same network.

Is it possible to do something simple with iptables?